# How to use the validation while editing the form in laravel?

Tags: validation, laravel-5, model-view-controller, backend

In My Blog Controller i have addBlog and updateBlog trying to validate them using validator function.
While adding blog it is working as expcted but while updateing blog it is again and again saying title alread exist, as i have selected title as uniue.
So how can i make this work for edit also.

I am using laravel 5.2

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'title' => 'required|max:255|unique:blogs',
        'meta_tags' => 'required|max:200',
        'content' => 'required|min:6',
    ]);
}



public function updateBlog(Request $request, $id)
{

    $this->middleware('auth');
    $user = Auth::user();

    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }

    try{
        $blog_Request = Blog::findOrFail($id);
        $blog_Request->title = $request->get('title');;
        $blog_Request->meta_tags = $request->get('meta_tags');
        $blog_Request->content = $request->get('content');
        $blog_Request->status = $request->get('status');

        if ($blog_Request->save()) {
            $request->session()->flash('message', 'Blog saved successfully!');
            $request->session()->flash('alert-class', 'alert-success');
        } else {
            $request->session()->flash('message', 'Some error occoured!');
            $request->session()->flash('alert-class', 'alert-danger');            
        }
        return redirect()->route('blog.edit_blog', $id);
    } catch (QueryException $ex) {
        print_r("Error on line number " . $ex->getLine() . " in file " . $ex->getFile() ."</br>");
    }

}


public function addBlog(Request $request)
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $user = Auth::user();

    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }

    $blog_Requests = new Blog;
    $blog_Requests->title = $request->get('title');;
    $blog_Requests->meta_tags = $request->get('meta_tags');
    $blog_Requests->content = $request->get('content');
    $blog_Requests->user_id = $user->id;

    try{
        if ($blog_Requests->save()) {
            $request->session()->flash('message', 'Blog saved successfully!');
            $request->session()->flash('alert-class', 'alert-success');
        } else {
            $request->session()->flash('message', 'Some error occoured!');
            $request->session()->flash('alert-class', 'alert-danger');            
        }
        return redirect()->route('blogs');
    } catch (QueryException $ex) {
        print_r("Error on line number " . $ex->getLine() . " in file " . $ex->getFile() ."</br>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is adding the `$blog->id` as the second parameter in your validator because you only want to throw a validation error if the user provides a title that is already used by a **different** blog.
:

```
return Validator::make($data, [
    'title' => 'required|max:255|unique:blogs,' . $blog->id,
    'meta_tags' => 'required|max:200',
    'content' => 'required|min:6',
]);
```

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/problem-with-unique-field-validation-on-update?page=1

Hope this help!